# How to fix "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" trying to get the location using Protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get an element's location using the Protractor (v6.0.0) method call **getLocation()**, however I'm getting the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at <Jasmine>
at actionFn (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:95:44)
at <Jasmine>
at actionResults.getWebElements.then(/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:468:44)
at <Jasmine>
at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_(/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:466:29)
```

Any clue how to resolve the issue?

Actually my code is really simple.

```
it('should compare login page with a baseline', async () => {
    let input =  element(by.id('mat-input-1'));
    await input.getLocation();
});
```

I expect the coordinates of the input which has id mat-input-1, but unfortunately I'm getting that exception.

Comment: It's really strange that that code would throw that exception.  The stack trace mentions `applyAction` and `getWebElements`, which are `ElementArrayFinder` methods, so I expected the code to involve an `element.all` or `$$` somewhere.  Are you sure that line is throwing that exception?  Maybe it's bailing at a different point in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor's [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) has a link to the [selenium-webdriver CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md), it lists:

> Changes for W3C WebDriver Spec Compliance
>
> - Replaced WebElement.getSize() and WebElement.getLocation() with a
>     single method, WebElement.getRect().

So it looks like you should use .getRect().

Now for Protractor 6 itself, this is clearly an issue with documentation. We recommend using 5.4.2 for now.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right! I used 5.4.2 and everything works like a charm. As you said, the documentation is not clear in this sense, actually Protractor web page did not work for several hours yesterday.

Comment: Yup. I did not update to 6 and actually we removed the "latest" tag from npm so the latest is 5.4.2 if you did a `npm install protractor`. We'll have more documentation around all of these changes. If you want to get started, a good first step is to move everything to async / await.